# Can a probability distribution function be a random variable?

Tags: probability

Let define the conditional probability as: $P(X<x|Y=y)$, can we consider this as a random variable??

Comment: I assume you wonder if $\mathbb{P}(X<x|Y)$ is a random variable? (If you know that $Y=y$, your conditional distribution is a degenerate and thus uninteresting random variable.) If so, then yes. In particular, it is a random variable defined on the space of (probability) measures of $X$. This is a random measure for the special case where the measure is also a probability measure, see for instance here if you are familiar with basic measure theory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_measure

Comment: @shuluka, any distribution function conditional or not, is a random variable. This random variable is a Uniform random variable on [01], this is known as the probability integral transform. Very useful in random variate generation.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform

Comment: @Lucas Your remarks might confuse the issue more than help it, for two reasons.  The first is that the distribution function is not necessarily a random variable on the original sample space.  The second is that its distribution is not necessarily uniform.  (Uniformity is equivalent to absolute continuity of the original variable.)  This obscures the fundamental simplicity of the definition of conditional probability in terms of conditional *expectations,* which are explicitly defined to be random variables (measurable with respect to a sub sigma algebra).

Comment: @whuber, good point about absolute continuity giving the uniform. I didn't want to make the comment-why I omitted-to complicated but you are right. After reading your comment I realize we can interpret this question either of 2 ways: (1) distribution function of the conditional distribution (as I have in prior comment but w/caveats) or (2) a random variable of $y$ which I think might be what you are referring to in your comment. Does this sound right?

Comment: @Lucas Yes, it sounds right.  My concern lies with the possibility of multiple interpretations.  (This afflicts the contents of many comments on this site because we simply don't have the space to elaborate on what we're trying to talk about!)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have random probability distributions. The Dirichlet Process provides an example of a distribution for random distributions. For a random *conditional* probability distribution, you could look to a DP mixture model, e.g. profile regression. This is a random function that happens to be a probability distribution.

For a random function (that is generally not a probability distribution) you could look at Gaussian Processes.